# What IP addresses to whitelist with Mongo DB atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, vercel

I am creating a web app and storing static data on MongoDB Atlas.  I fetch the data with my client frontend and display it on the website.

What IP's should I whitelist on MongoDB?  I have heard that allowing access to all IP addresses is not safe, however I can't really see a work around.

I am host the site on Vercel if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: The best bet would be to ask your hosting provider.  They probably have something already on their website.

Comment: The [Vercel](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-allowlist-deployment-ip-address) docs advise whitelisting all IPs. That sounds like a bad practice, but may be your only option with that host.

Answer (score 0):

Create an environment variable file on server with database connection string in it. This file should be on the server and must allow all IP through atlas.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).